# Blackberry MenuItem Deprecated

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jde

I am trying to use the MenuItem class of BlackBerry JDE 6.0 and I am encountering an error "The constructor MenuItem String(String, int, int) is deprecated". I am implementing it using a subclass under the MainScreen class. below is the sample deprecated code:

```
public class UiFunMainScreen extends MainScreen{

   class LoginMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    public LoginMenuItem() {

    super("Login", 20, 10);
    }

    public void run() {
    login();
    }
}
class ClearMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    public ClearMenuItem() {
    super("Clear", 10, 20);
    }

    public void run() {
    clearTextFields();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following version of code to create a MenuItem:

```
class MyUiScreen extends MainScreen
 {
     public MyUiScreen()
     {
         MenuItem myItem = new MenuItem(
                 new StringProvider("My Menu Item"), 
                 0x230000, 
                 0
             );
 // rest of codes...
```

from the [RIM BlackBerry API 6.0 Documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html)

**Creating menu items by subclassing and implementing Runnable**

*If subclassing the extending class must implement the Runnable interface, which in turn supports abstract dispatching of menu actions on activation.*

```
...
// setup the menu items
MenuItem item = new MyMenuItem();
menu.addItem(item);
...
class MyMenuItem extends MenuItem {
    MyMenuItem() {
        super(MyResourceBundle.getBundle(), MyResource.MY_MENU_ITEM, 0x230000, 0);
    }
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Explore the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#MenuItem%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29).